# Are there any publicly available horizon servers or do you always have to run your own private servers?

Tags: horizon, server

Stellarbeat.io has a list of hundreds of horizon servers, but if you try to connect to any of them with a simple GET request (like to get account info), it immediately closes the connection.

Are they all for private use?

For example, https://169.47.111.126:11625/accounts/GAHLAL3CCAW5FCFDIKDVH3I2WR46DAJJT75SMZ2OSXIFQXSP4QDRV57C or any other URL listed on stellarbeat.io just immediately closes the connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Stellar Development Foundation (SDF) [runs two publicly available](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/) instances: https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/  for test network and https://horizon.stellar.org/ for public network.

If you want to run your own instance (for example to avoid rate limiting), you can use the [Stellar Quickstart Docker Image](https://github.com/stellar/docker-stellar-core-horizon) provided by SDF.

Answer (score 4):

The servers listed at stellarbeat.io are not stellar-horizon servers but stellar-core nodes.

stellar-core:

- handling p2p network communication with a binary protocol
- don't have a public http(s) interface
- (optionally) validating transaction data

stellar-horizon:

- handling client communication via http
- gets its data from a stellar-core

I guess nobody advertises their nodes because there is no real incentive to provide endpoints to the public. Even contrary many operators have some kind of commercial interest and operating public horizons would mean providing free infrastructure to your competitors.

Feel free to use my horizon (without warranty, and I don't think its more reliable than stellar.org) until you have your own one => https://horizon.sui.li